# PHP pass variable by reference using ?: operators

Tags: php

I have a problem when I try to call a function that expects a reference as parameter. The function works totally fine when I pass any variable to it, however if I pass a variable to it through the means of the ? and : if/else operators, I get the error `Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference`.

The function looks as following:

```
public function testFunction(&$var) {
    //It does nothing.
}
```

Now I'm attempting to call the function the following way:

```
$yes = 'yes';
$no = 'no';

$this->testFunction(
    TRUE ? $yes : $no
);
```

However if I do `$this->testFunction($yes)` it does work. What am I doing wrong here? Can I not use '?' and ':' for this, and if not what are my alternatives to make sure that `testFunction` will get a reference to the right data?

Comment: That's because you are not passing the variable but its value.. so the expression si evaluated first and the passed argument is a string not a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not passing the variable but its value instead. The expression si evaluated first and the passed argument is a string not a variable.

You can do it like this instead:

```
$yes = 'yes';
$no = 'no';

if (true) {
    $this->testFunction($yes);
} else {
    $this->testFunction($no);
}
```

Comment: Or just define variable `$boolean = true ? $yes : $no;` and then pass it to function `$this->testFunction($boolean);`

Comment: You can do that but the reference passed will be the reference of `$boolean` instead of `$yes` or `$no`. So if you want to affect any of those 2 variables inside the function it will not work

Comment: Oh I assumed that after it evaluated it would simply put the variable instead of it's value. I hoped I didn't have to make an actual if/else but simply do the evaluation inside the function call.

Comment: @MateiMihai true, forgot about reference